# RAML how to document nested params

Tags: documentation, raml

How to document nested parameters (no matter query or body) with RAML? For example:

```
{ 
  "credentials: {
    "login": "some-login",
    "key": "some-key"
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no matter query or body"?

Comment: @DavidDossot I meant that no matter if I passed params in URL query or postbody.

Comment: By query do you mean in the query section of the URI?

Answer (score 0):

This is a JSON entity so it needs to be specified in [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) and referred to as a [request](http://raml.org/spec.html#body) or [response](http://raml.org/spec.html#responses) body.

Comment: Yes, but how about postbody params which should have such schema?

Comment: From your comment under the question, it seems these params can be passed as query params as well. Here you seem to suggest they can be passed in the body entity either as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`. Please edit your question and make the different scenarios you want to support clearer.